# Reading a .dat file as "rb" read binary

Tags: php, binary, fopen

I have a folder `\folder\` above the webroot that contains `.php`, `.inc`, `.dat` files

- the `.php` can access the `.inc` no problem
- but when the `.inc` tries to access the `.dat` using `fopen('mydat.dat', "rb");` it gives an error that it can't find `mydat.dat` **inside** `\folder\myinc.inc`

Of course it can't find it since `.inc` is a file not a folder. Why is php treating it as such?

Any ideas why php is trying to find the `.dat` inside the `.inc`?

or any other alternatives to `fopen($filename, "rb")`?

Comment: Even if you don't understand meaning of the error message, other people do. So, it's always very good idea to copy and paste exact error message you've got. It would save your time and other people from guessing. It doesn't say "it can't find mydat.dat inside \folder\myinc.inc". It just stated a filename where error occurred.

Comment: No, I am correct. It's the way PHP writes it's error messages. You an try various errors, but all has the same template. Everything in the same way: "in some\path" IS the name of the file where error occurred. Trust me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comments, I think you expect fopen to use the include_path.

fopen() doesn't use the include_path by default(unlike include). It's an option. See the manual.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 1):

Learn filesystem basics. 
your working directory is still in the webroot. it doesnt change it to the \folder\ (although it seems new versions of PHP do look files within current file location).

Anyway if you want to open a file in the same directory, `dirname(__FILE__)` is always for you

in the myinc.inc you can use

```
fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/mydat.dat', "rb");
```

Comment: @donpal why don't you try my code instead of empty argue? And what's the issue with .htaccess? your working directory is out of .htaccess reach

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have [`safe_mode`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode) enabled, but don't have a value for [`open_basedir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir), or have the file outside it. Put the .dat file in a path given to that option.

Comment: From the documentation I linked to: "This directive is ***NOT*** affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off." Please check `open_basedir` as well.

Comment: So are you saying that `open_basedir` isn't present at all?

Comment: safe mode sounds like safe mode. It has these words, `safe mode` in the error message. Go figure.

Answer (score -1):

When ever we deal with files in php. It is necessary to give path+file name to avoid such type of errors.